# Androidx ViewPager2 incompatible types: ViewPagerAdapter cannot be converted to Adapter

Tags: java, android, androidx, android-jetpack, android-viewpager2

I am using ViewPager2, and I get the following error on `viewPager2.setAdapter`:

> incompatible types: ViewPagerAdapter cannot be converted to Adapter

MainActivty

```
viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),fragmentList);
viewPager2.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
```

ViewPagerAdapter

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private List<PagerFragment> fragments;


    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<PagerFragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter#getItem(int)
     */
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter#getCount()
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use a `ViewPager` v1 adapter with `ViewPager2`.  You should convert your adapter to implement [`FragmentStateAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/viewpager2/adapter/FragmentStateAdapter) instead.

See [this section of the migration documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration#adapter-classes) for more information.  In particular, you'll want to rename your `getCount` method to `getItemCount`, as well as renaming `getItem` to `createFragment` and making it return a new `Fragment` each time rather than re-using instances.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments;
private ArrayList<String> titles;

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
    super(fm);
    this.fragments=new ArrayList<>();
    this.titles=new ArrayList<>();

}


@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragments.size();
}


public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title){

    fragments.add(fragment);
    titles.add(title);

}

@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return titles.get(position);
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks @shimma but i am trying to use viewpager2 adapter, i think FragmentPagerAdapter is of viewPager1.